# Scala Option[Seq[A]] exists

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-option

I have the following code:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Launcher extends App {

  val people = Option(Seq(Person("Andrii", 20), Person("John", 35), Person("Sam", 15)))

  def filterPeople(list: Option[Seq[Person]]): Boolean =
    list.getOrElse(Nil)
      .exists(_.age < 18)

  assert(filterPeople(people) == true)
}
```

The question is: can I process `Option[Seq[A]]` more elegantly and safely without `getOrElse(Nil)`?

```
list.getOrElse(Nil)
      .exists(_.age < 18)
```

I have found another approach to this:

```
list.exists(_.exists(_.age > 18))
```

Note: I have `Option[Seq[A]]` just because of REST contract.

Comment: "Note: I have Option[Seq[A]] just because of REST contract."

In this case my suspicion is that you'll quite often need to treat `None` and `Some(Nil)` as equivalent, and `getOrElse(Nil)` has the benefit of working in _all_ of those cases automatically, compared to `fold` or `exists` approaches. 

So I'd say `getOrElse` is the more elegant and safe approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointed by @NimrodArgov, I would prefer to use pattern matching for checking the list type as it is more readable:

```
def filterPeople(list: Option[Seq[Person]]): Boolean = {
  list match {
    case Some(people) => people.exists(_.age < 18)
    case None => false
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `case None` here, so the compiler can check for complete pattern match. `case _` is a bit dangerous sometimes, better not make it a habit.

Comment: Thank you, this is the way how it is currently implemented. I agree with you that it is much readable. There is one more option (one man sad that it is idiomatic monads): `list.map(_.exists(_.age < 18)) match { case Some(true) => true case _ => false }`. What do you think?

Comment: I agree with what @Reactormonk says, it is even more readable with the `None` case. Your solution @Andrii is good but, personally, I think that for someone that reads the code it may be a little more confusing to use the `map` and then the pattern matching over a `Option[Boolean]`.

Comment: @CamiloSampedro I share this option with you.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility.

```
def filterPeople(list: Option[Seq[Person]]): Boolean =
  list.fold(false)(_.exists(_.age < 18))
```

Tested:

```
filterPeople(people)  // res0: Boolean = true
filterPeople(None)    // res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: I much prefer a pattern match, as it makes the code more readable.

Comment: Thank you. `fold` approach looks good to me. It is more readable than `getOrElse(Nil)`